# Localization - Only few strings are converted to Hindi when performing localization in Android App

Tags: android, string, android-studio, localization

I have a method in base activity called setLanguage(Context context, String language).It takes context of the activity and the language string in which the localization has to be done.**The problem is that only android system's hindi strings are being displayed and not of strings.xml(hi).
For example i am able to see the translation of monday - सोमवार but not of any other strings i have defined in strings.xml(hi).**

```
public final void setLanguage(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        setLanguage(context, locale);
}


public final void setLanguage(Context context, Locale locale) {       
        LanguageSetting.setLanguage(activity, locale);
        notifyLanguageChanged();
}


public class LanguageSetting {
private static final String PREFERENCE_LANGUAGE = "pref_language";
private static final String KEY_LANGUAGE = "key_language";
private static Locale DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = Locale.ENGLISH;

public static void setDefaultLanguage(Locale locale) {
    DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = locale;
}

public static Locale getDefaultLanguage() {
    return DEFAULT_LANGUAGE;
}

public static void setLanguage(Context context, Locale locale) {
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getLanguagePreference(context).edit();
    editor.putString(KEY_LANGUAGE, locale.toString());
    editor.apply();
}

public static Locale getLanguage(Context context) {
    String[] language = getLanguagePreference(context)
            .getString(KEY_LANGUAGE, DEFAULT_LANGUAGE.toString())
            .split("_");
    Locale locale;
    if (language.length == 1) {
        locale = new Locale(language[0]);
    } else if (language.length == 2) {
        locale = new Locale(language[0], language[1].toUpperCase());
    } else {
        locale = DEFAULT_LANGUAGE;
    }
    return locale;
}

private static SharedPreferences getLanguagePreference(Context context) {
    return context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_LANGUAGE, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the answer.I had hard coded the locale in the gradle file.

```
        android { 
   defaultConfig {
        ...
        resConfigs "en" 
        ...
   }
}
```

I just needed to remove `resConfigs "en"`

Answer (score 0):

I think this link might have the answer your looking for.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2900144/2781626

Here's the code from the post if your in a hurry and just need the code and you plan on checking the link out at another time to learn more why this code might be your solution. I believe you can keep some/a lot of your current code, but you might need to change some of it around in order to do an app-wide locale change.

```
`Resources res = context.getResources();
// Change locale settings in the app.
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
android.content.res.Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.setLocale(new Locale(language_code.toLowerCase())); // API 17+ only.
// Use conf.locale = new Locale(...) if targeting lower versions
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);`
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Zefyr but i finally got the answer ! The problem was in gradle where i hard coded the locale        android { 
       defaultConfig {
            ...
            resConfigs "en", "fr" 
            ...
       }
    }